# array of images to html

Tags: javascript, html

I', writing a js/html script for a class project. I need to print out an array of names and then and array with pictures to each element of the first array. I get "unidentified" as output when I try to print this out. if I add.src to the end of picturesArray only the picture path shows up. Here's my code:

```
<script>
      let profilesArray = [
        "Simon, 25",
        "Erlend, 22",
        "Karsten, 19",
        "Angelica, 22",
        "Wilma, 24",
        "Celine, 20",
      ];
      let picturesArray = [
        "images/man1.jpg",
        "images/man2.jpg",
        "images/man3.jpg",
        "images/woman1.jpg",
        "images/woman3.jpg",
        "images/woman3.jpg",
      ];

      let profList = "";

      for (let i = 0; i < profilesArray.length; i++) {
        document.write((profilesArray[i] += "<br/>"));
        for (let y = 0; y < picturesArray.length; y++) {
          document.write((picturesArray[y]. += "<br/>"));
          break;
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What is `document.write((profilesArray[i] += "<br/>"));` supposed to do?

Comment: it prints out a profile name and age

Comment: and the other array contains the images for each profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dot(.) on the line  `document.write((picturesArray[y]. += "<br/>"));` , remove it and try  `document.write((picturesArray[y] += "<br/>"));`

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < profilesArray.length; i++) {
        document.write((profilesArray[i] += "<br/>"));
        for (let y = 0; y < picturesArray.length; y++) {
          document.write(picturesArray[y.src] + "<br/>");
          break;
        }
      }

Comment: You don't need picturesArray[y.src] just picturesArray[y]

Comment: ok gotcha, but now it just prints out the path of the image as text under each name, age

Comment: In order to show an actual image, you have to create that tag, assign an src attribute and it's value, then append it to the document, body or wherever you want.

Something like this
`    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = picturesArray[y];`

Now you just need to append it to parent element

Comment: Still gives me unidentifed :( Is there anything I need to include in my html doc perhaps?

Comment: Try something like this:

`for (let i = 0; i < profilesArray.length; i++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < picturesArray.length; y++) {
    document.write(('Author: ' + profilesArray[i] + "<br/>Image: <img src=" + picturesArray[y] + " /><br/>"));
  }
}`

Just make sure you have all these images inside your /images/ folder

Comment: Glad I could help! Your're Welcome. Just check the answer as correct.

Comment: update, It only shows the same name for al the pictures

Comment: Then you should try something like this:

`var users = [{
  name: 'Name 1',
  image: '/images/imagename.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'Name 2',
  image: '/images/imagename2.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'Name 3',
  image: '/images/imagenam3.jpg'
} ,{
  name: 'Name 4',
  image: '/images/imagenam4.jpg'
}];

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var user = users[i];
  document.write('Profile: ' + user.name + '<br> Image: <img src="'+ user.image + '" alt="'+ user.name + '" />')
}`

Comment: I got it to print out the names in order, however, it prints out the same picture for each name.

Comment: Try using my latest example in the previous comment because of the array of objects and each object has specific image and a name. Just make sure that "image" url is not same. Provide a different "image" value of each "user".

Comment: `code` for (let i = 0; i < profilesArray.length; i++) {
        document.write(profilesArray[i]);
        for (let y = 0; y < picturesArray.length; y++) {
          document.write("<img src=" + picturesArray[y] + " /><br/>");
          break;
        }
      }

Comment: You won't be able to use that code. Use mine because it's a proper solution for what you're looking for.

Comment: It works like a clock now! thank you so much. Out of curiosity what does the(' " alt= " ') and ('  " />') do?